# carriage settings

Tags: vim

Where I can find the carriage settings of Vim? I use Cream version.

I need to reduce the frequency of carriage blinking.

It will be very helpful if somebody show a comprehensive tutorial how to adjust Vim settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"carriage blinking"? Uhmm, could it be "cursor blinking"?

If that is the case, try reading this tutorial ... [Configuring the cursor](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor).

Comment: Cursor or caret is the word he's looking for.